# Apache crashed/not starting up while using Public IP

Tags: apache-2.4

1. My staging server Public IP - `12.91.183.66` (consider it as example)
2. Staging server system IP (local) - `192.155.0.2` (consider it as example)

When I access magento on staging server using IP `100.12.13.14`, it works and I have changed same IP in `core_config_data` under `base_url`. The same has been mentioned in `http.conf` - `Listen 100.12.13.14:80`

But if I change local IP to Public IP i.e. `100.200.300.400`, in `core_config_data` under `base_url` and also in `http.conf`, apache keeps getting crashed OR not starting up.

How do I bind my staging server IP in `http.conf` to access magento publicly ?

P.S. Staging server has both IIS and Xampp running. IIS server is running public IP with port 8080 and it is accessible publicly. Even if I stop that server and run Magento, it does not work with Apache

Comment: Could it be that Apache cannot bind to the specified ip and port because another process is already listening there? Have a look at `netstat` and, more importantly, the apache logs.

Comment: The dev box has both IIS server and xampp running. IIS is running public IP with port 8080 and it is accessible publicly. Even if I stop that server and run Magento, it does not work with Apache; though it works with local machine IP

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy we should bind to internal IP address or localhost, we can't bind to public. please try to find apache listen on which port?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT - Yes I have mentioned local machine IP in httpd.conf. It works only using port 8080 i.e. `192.155.0.2:8080` and not `192.155.0.2` ? What could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

> It works only using port 8080

It seems your Apache listen on port 8080, we can find the settings in this file `ports.conf`.

After your stop IIS service, restart Apahce, can you browse it from that VM? use `http://localhost:8080` to browse it.

Please run this command to get port information: `netstat -ant | findstr 8080`.